# mmread no longer working

Tags: windows, matlab

The mmread function used to work perfectly until yesterday! Since then I've been getting this error:

> Error using mmread (line 435) dimensions do not match data size. Too
>   little data.

Has anyone ever got the same problem? What should I do? I am working on Windows 7 Professional N, 64bit, and Matlab R2012b. The code is correct, cause it works just fine on my virtual machine!

I tried to uninstalled all the recently installed programs (Java, video tools and others) but still not working!

Link to the function http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8028-mmread

Comment: Have you tried to step through the `mmread` code to see what is happening prior to line 435?  What are the values for `scanline`,`width`, and `height`?

Comment: `mmread` is not part of Matlab so I assume that you mean [this function](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8028-mmread). Edit your question to show your code with how you use this. What kind of movie are trying to read? What codec? You say that this used to work – have you gone back tried run it on other video files?

Comment: I found the problem, although I have not yet understood why it was a problem! I had installed K-Lite codec pack! When I uninstalled it everything worked perfect again